# combinatorics and plane geometry

Tags: combinatorics

If you received a simple question from plane geometry asking for the number of points of intersection by two lines, would this be considered a proper question?
If the answer could only reliably and accurately  be found with a computer, would such a question be automatically rejected?

Comment: Can you please add some additional background? For example, "the intersection points by two lines" is a rather vague concept. Do the lie on the same plane? Which space are we considering?

Comment: What do you mean by "a proper question?"

Comment: I will simply state the problem and let you decide.  Define a k-sector to be a line that divides a vertex of a regular n-gon into k equal angles.  The line extends both through the interior of the n-gon and to the exterior of the n-gon.  You will get n*(n+1)/2 lines that will intersect at points (a)inside the n-gon, (b)on the edge of the n-gon, (c)possibly through the vertex of an opposite vertex (as with a square or hexagon), and (d) outside the n-gon.  Answers are sought for numbers for these four questions when the k-sectors travel clockwise round the interior dividing the angles.

Comment: By "proper question" I mean worthy of experimentation by using a computer to answer.  I recently asked the editors about computer recreation and experimentation being done by any users of this site; to this I  got no reply.

Comment: In a rush at noisy public library=clarification needed.  A -sector will be one of k-1 lines  dividing a vertex into equal parts.  Thus for a square you get 1 line to divide into 2 45-degree angles, 2 lines for 3 angles of 30 degrees,  3 lines for 4 22.5 degree, and the last 5 equal angles of 18 degrees each.